# How to access specific cell of a Excel table using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to reference an excel table by name, then reference a column in the table by its name, and finally iterate through all rows in that column.

So far I have managed to connect openpyxl to my spreadsheet and read values by directly looking at cells. However, I would prefer to instead use table names and column names instead of hardcoded cell coordinates.

```py
# Open my excel file, and save it as a variable to use later
input_excel_file = pyxl.load_workbook(path_backup_excel_file, data_only=True)
# Open the specific sheet from the excel file
sheet_panels_to_run = input_excel_file['Panels to Run']

# This reads values fine, but does not use the table.
print(sheet_panels_to_run['a2'].value)

# Save the table to a variable. This part works fine.
request_table = sheet_panels_to_run.tables['RequestTable']

# I'm able to narrow down to a specific column, but not sure how to see values from its rows yet.
print(request_table.tableColumns['Panel Name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the openpyxl [`Table`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.table.html#openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table) class doesn't seem to have to a convenient built-in method for iterating over its cells. The following should work however:

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import range_boundaries
import openpyxl as pyxl  # v3.0.10

# Access excel sheet
input_excel_file = pyxl.load_workbook(path_backup_excel_file, data_only=True)
sheet_panels_to_run = input_excel_file['Panels to Run']

# Access named table
request_table = sheet_panels_to_run.tables['RequestTable']

# Get range boundaries of table
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(request_table.ref)

# Construct headers lookup dictionary
headers = {
    col_name: col_idx
    for (col_idx, col_name)
    in enumerate(request_table.column_names)
}

# Get relative column index of target column
target_col_idx = headers['Panel Name']

# Loop over all data values in target column
for i in range(min_row + 1, max_row + 1):
    value = sheet_panels_to_run.cell(i, min_col + target_col_idx).value
    print(value)
```